# Bash script for historical load from netezza to linux server directory

Tags: bash, netezza

bash/python script which will extract data from Netezza and create files on Unix server.
It should take the below 4 parameters:

1. Database.table name
2. date column which will be used for delta logic (optional)
3. begin date (optional)
4. end date (optional)

script name:NZ_Extract.ksh
The script should create the below query to extract data:
`select * from database.table_name where column_name >= begin_Date and column_name <= end_date;`

Extract file should be delimited - Use '|' as delimiter for now
Extract file name should be - database.tablename_endDate_currentDate.txt

eg with all 4 parameters:
run command:
`NZ_Extract.ksh POR.product updt_Ts 20200101 20200331`
Query:
`select * from  POR.product where  updt_Ts >= '20200101' and  updt_Ts<= '20200331' ;` --> you will have to cast the dates accordingly.
Extract file:
POR.PRODUCT_20210331_20210413.txt

eg with 3 parameter: (without end_Date)
run command:
`NZ_Extract.ksh POR.product updt_Ts 20200101`
Query:
`select * from  POR.product where  updt_Ts >= '20200101' ;`
Extract file:
POR.PRODUCT_20210413_20210413.txt  --> use current date in name

eg with 1 parameter:
run command:
`NZ_Extract.ksh POR.product`
Query:
`select * from  POR.product ;`
Extract file:
POR.PRODUCT_19000101_20210413.txt

Comment: What have you [ATTEMPTED](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  And how have you [FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ?

Comment: Please post your actual code if it exists, so we can help you